# NodeMailer : getaddrinfo EAI_FAIL Error in Fastcomet mail

Tags: node.js, express, email, smtp, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer for sending mail and I am using Fastcomet for mail provider. But the thing is I am geeting **getaddrinfo EAI_FAIL**. I have searched a lot and did not found anyting. I have used only on special character @ in my password. I have also changed my password and checked but the error is still remains. What I do? Can anyone suggest me what I do now? Here below is my code and the error message.

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: HOST, // smtp server here
    port: PORT, // connection port
    // secure: true, // use SSL or not
    auth: {
        user: USER_ID, // smtp login user
        pass: USER_PASSWORD, // smtp login pass
    },
});

let mailOptions = {
    from: SENDER_EMAIL,
    to: RECIVER_EMAIL,
    subject: "Test",
    text: "Message send from Admin",
};

// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error.message);
    }
    console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
});
```

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: try this code. and if you have issue, let know it, i will help you

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, nodemailer doesn't work since either npm or node version.
So last time, i did it with `node-mailjet`.
Try it with this code.

```
npm install node-mailjet
```

`send.mail.js` file:

```
const mailjet = require ('node-mailjet').connect('03c9150ac11402d921d7126519711ac7', 'a501283852994580f7a2bb5f2d7ae875');

module.exports = async (to, content) => {
  const subject = content.Subject;
  const text = content.TextPart;
  const html = content.HTMLPart;
  const task =content.TextPart;
  await mailjet
  .post("send", {'version': 'v3.1'})
  .request({
    "Messages":[
      {
        "From": {
          "Email": "tomer@expertinvest.co.il",
          "Name": "Expert Ivnest Team"
        },
        "To": [
          {
            "Email": to,
            "Name": "ttt"
          }
        ],
        "Subject": subject,
        "TextPart": text,
        "HTMLPart": html,
        "CustomID": task
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

In `route.js` file, add this part.

```
const sendEmail = require('../send.mail')

sendEmail(req.body.email, content).then(()=>{
    res.json({});
});
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is the work of .connect() method in require('node-mailjet')?

Comment: @Abhijit, it is cloud mailject server access key

Comment: this is my access key, i will remove a day later

Comment: within a day, finish to test with mine. and you can create your keys in mailjet.com

Comment: cloud meiljet, they make connection your mail to customer mail

Comment: ok Thanks I will upvote it and buddy upvote my question so that It can reach to other people. And thanks for the keys.

Comment: Using mailjet has a down side because on a new account the mail sending is block after creating the account